# JSON stored in MongoDB contains \,\r,\n characters

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I have JSON array and I created new JSON structure out of it.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("key", jsonString);
```

where `jsonString` is the string form of JSON array **(prettified form)**.

Then I am saving the JSON data into MongoDB like this:-

```
Document doc = Document.parse(jsonObject.toString());
collection.insertOne(doc);
```

The problem is the JSON data stored in MongoDB **contains \,\r and \n** characters everywhere what wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 0):

Create map from your object, Then create BasicDBObject(map) which is mongo DBObject and try to insert this dbObject.

```
public void insert(Object object){
DBObject dbObject = convert(object);
collection.insert(dbObject);
}

public DBObject convert(Object object){
mapObject = [
key:value,
key:value
]    
return new BasicDBObject(mapObject);
}
```

Comment: Why do i need to create map object ? i already have json object.

Comment: Here BasicDBObject needs Map to create dbObject.